# Lagrange remainder for a Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Why is the Lagrange form of the remainder term for a $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$ not evaluated at $a$ but instead somewhere between $x$ and $a$?

Comment: In general, we do not know the exact position where we have to calculate the derivate, we only know that it must be somewhere between $x$ and $a$. But the remainder term allows to estimate the error we make by truncating the taylor series at some point. In particular, we can determine an upper bound of the error.

Comment: Let's say that I stop the expansion at n. Then till n the inputs for derivatives will be a. And for its reminader the input should be z (which is a<z<x). But if I were to stop the expansion at n+1, now the input for n+1 derivative will be a. Why the input gets changed for remainder and the Taylor polynomial ?

Comment: Check [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: Oh so basically since we know the next derivative exists, we can use the MVT to say that since the derivative exist, it must be between a<z<x?

Comment: Can you please answer one more thing. We know the expansion can be carried out till infinity. Yet sometimes we stop the expansion at 2nd or 3rd power and consider the remainder to be the next 3rd or 4th power. Is this an approximation for the function or an exact value? If exact value then please tell me how does just a single power continuation for a remainder fulfill all the remaining powers not used either in Taylor or remainder?

Comment: It is an approximation, usually due to alternating series remainder. Could you provide an actual example of that scenario so I may be more specific?

Comment: The (n-th) Taylor *polynomial* of $f$ is a polynomial; its has no remainder term. It is the Taylor *expansion* of $f$ that has the remainder term.

Comment: @Jack my question is why the Taylor expansion at a minus the nth Taylor polynomial at a equal to n+1th derivative of the function at z. Is it because the partial sum of the remaining Taylor polynomial at a equal n+1 derivative of the function at z?

Comment: @FaiqRaees: I'm afraid I don't understand your English. You might want to articulate your question in a better way. Are you asking a question regarding [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), or the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)? They are related but different.

Comment: If f(x) is the Taylor expansion and T_n(x) is the nth Taylor polynomial at a then is this true $$f(x)-T_n(x) =\frac{f^{n+1}(z)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty c_k(x-a)^k$$

Comment: What makes you believe that$$\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}=\sum_{k>n}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$? Take the example function I have prescribed below and you will find this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

I'll change the notation but it should be clear. We start by with an easy to check relation, that is:

$$\int_0^xf^{(1)}(t)dt=f(x)-f(0)$$

with $f$ of class $C^\infty$, naturally. Because going with this formula won't give exactly the same formula I'll change it a bit as

$$\int_0^xf^{(1)}(x-t)dt=f(0)-f(x)$$

The mean value theorem applied to this relation gives:

$$\int_0^xf^{(1)}(x-t)dt = xf^{(1)}(c)$$

so by using both relations we get what is commonly known as the mean value theorem, and also the relation that you first find on Wikipedia on this topic

$$xf^{(1)}(c) = f(x) - f(0)$$

I won't use this. Just wanted to link those 2 equivalent forms  of the same relation to make sure that no problems arise here. What I'm going to use in the following is the first relation slightly rewritten as

$$f(x) = f(0)-\int_0^xf^{(1)}(x-t)dt$$

Let's integrate by parts such that the integral becomes

$$\int_0^xf^{(1)}(x-t)dt = tf^{(1)}(x-t)|_0^x + \int_0^xtf^{(2)}(x-t)dt = -xf^{(1)}(0) + \int_0^xtf^{(2)}(t)dt$$

Combine the last 2 relations and we get

$$f(x) = f(0)+xf^{(1)}(0) - \int_0^xtf^{(2)}(x-t)dt$$

Repeat the integration by parts and the above relation becomes

$$f(x) = f(0) + xf^{(1)}(0) + \frac{x^2}{2} f^{(2)}(0) - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^xt^2f^{(3)}(x-t)dt$$

$$...$$

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{x^i}{i!} f^{(i)}(0) - \frac{1}{n!}\int_0^xt^{n}f^{(n+1)}(x-t)dt$$

Here you can recognise that the sum is the **Taylor polynomial of degree $n$** and the integral is the **Reminder**.

And finally to answer you question regarding why the reminder is evaluated at some point $0<c<x$. By using the third formula on the reminder we get

$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{n+1}(c)$$

And there you have it. Caution though, there might be typos, but the reasoning should be ok.

And another thing. This method does not ensure that the Taylor polynomial converges to the function. That's a different story. This only shows where the reminder and the polynomial come from.

Comment: +1 I hope this is clear to the OP, because it is clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The [Lagrange remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) comes from the exact remainder of a Taylor polynomial:

$$f(x)=P_n(x)+\int_a^x\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n~\mathrm dt$$

By applying the [mean value theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mean-ValueTheorem.html), we see that this reduces to

$$f(x)=P_n(x)+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$$

If $x>a$, then $\xi\in(a,x)$. If $x<a$, then $\xi\in(x,a)$.

Comment: Yeah can you please tell me how the integral equation is achieved ? What I think by remainder is $$f(x)=\sum_1^n T_n(x)+ \sum_{n+1}^\infty T_n(x)$$ where the second term is the remainder.

Comment: @FaiqRaees It is a natural consequence of integrating by parts. And why should we have$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$? Take for example,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2},&x\ne0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$centered at $a=0$. You will find your remainder is false, but my remainder holds true.

Comment: But yeah that's my point if Taylor expansion is expansion till infinity and if we break it at some point shouldn't the remainder term carry on till infinity?

Comment: @FaiqRaees That isn't quite clear, I've never seen such. Usually, I see$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^n=0\implies\text{convergence to function}$$But have you tried the example function I've given above?

Comment: oh yes that's the exact function I have been told to use. Sorry for un clarity. But I am still wondering why the remainder term not the sum till infinite powers rather than just be the term with the next power.

Comment: What you are talking about is "Taylor series". *Not* every function $f$ has such series. "Taylor expansion" is for functions having derivatives up to degree $n$. Please check the assumptions of Taylor's theorem and clarify your question.

Comment: @FaiqRaees It is not the next term, since the next term uses $f^{(n+1)}(a)$ instead of $f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$. And your "wondering" is false since you've assumed that all functions equal their Taylor series, when this is simply not true.

Comment: Oh yes sorry for the little details. By the next term what I meant is the next power. So what you're imply is for a Taylor polynomial at $a$, remainder of the next power at z equals the remaining Taylor terms at a?

Comment: Could you be more clear? @FaiqRaees